# Rails to_json :methods that have parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have an array of model objects that have an owner method. This method needs a parameter to be passed into it to work. I need to serialize the model objects to json and include the value of the owner method.

How would I go about passing the parameter into the `to_json` method I currently use the

```
objects.to_json(:methods => :owner)
```

to include the owner method but as I am not passing the parameter it does not work.

Comment: How are you using the JSON? Why can't you pass parameters to #to_json?

Answer (score 20):

NOTE: Comment applies to Rails 2.3, haven't tried this w/ Rails 3.

I don't believe you can do this w/ the way to_json works, so I think you have two options:

1.Prep your objects by calling a method to stash the right value away in a variable which the 'owner' method then reads during the to_json call.

2.Overriding as_json in your model:

```
def as_json(options = {})
    json = super(options)
    json['owner'] = owner(options[:param_for_owner])
    json
end
```

Then in your to_json call just pass in :param_for_owner:

```
objects.to_json(:param_for_owner => 'foo')
```

Note that where you inject your value will depend on how your ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json is configured.

Comment: If you want to use this as_json override method for a particular class, but do not need to include 'owner' every time, you can add "if owner[:param_for_owner]" after the json['owner']... line to make it optional.

Comment: It is ok: if the methods need parameters, it means the JSON representation of the object depends on those parameters so it is normal to have a custom behavior. Otherwise, you could create another method that calls the `as_json` method. Eg. `object.as_json_with_owner(owner)`