# Rails: overriding as_json for dynamic value -- is there a smarter way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to output a list of affiliate links, each tagged to identify the current user.  It would be simple in HTML, but we're writing an API, so the output is JSON.

I have it working, but it seems overly complicated.  Is this the best approach?

My model, AffiliateLink contains a field (the raw HTML of the link) that I'll transform and output on the fly by adding a token.  I have a model method that produces the replacement -- it is non-trivial because we use multiple affiliates and each has a special transformation rule that this method knows about:

```
def link_with_token(user_token)
  # some gnarly code that depends on a lot of stuff the model knows
  # that returns a proper link
end
```

To get my correct link html in JSON I have done these things:

- add `attr_accessor :link_html` to model
- add an instance method to set the new accessor

...

```
def set_link_html(token)
  self.link_html = link_with_tracking_token(token)
end
```

- override `as_json` in the model, replacing the original html_code with link_html

...

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(:methods => :link_html, :except => :html_code)
end
```

- iterate over the collection returned in the controller method to do the transformation

...

```
def index
  @links = Admin::AffiliateLink.all  # TODO, pagination, etc.

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json do
      @links.each do |link|
        link.set_link_html(account_tracking_token)
      end
      render json: @links
    end
  end
end
```

This seems like a lot of stuff to do just to get my teensy-weensy transformation done.  Helpful suggestions (relating to this problem and not to other aspects of the code, which is in flux now) are welcome.

Comment: Are options like `Rabl` or just actually using a template to help render your `json` vs. overriding the `as_json` method out of the question?

Comment: I have dabbled with RABL but it seems to present more hurdles (especially as a result of limited doc).  Someday, I'll just read the code and figure out how to use it.  For now, `as_json` seems to be plenty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**1)** A quick solution to your problem (as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5146541/334121)):

affiliate_links_controller.rb

```
def index
  @links = Admin::AffiliateLink.all  # TODO, pagination, etc.

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json do
      render json: @links.to_json(:account_tracking_token => account_tracking_token)
    end
  end
end
```

AffiliateLink.rb

```
# I advocate reverse_merge so passed-in options overwrite defaults when option
# keys match.
def as_json(options = {})
  json = super(options.reverse_merge(:except => :html_code))
  json[:link_with_token] = link_with_token(options[:account_tracking_token])
  json
end
```

---

**2)** A more hardcore solution, if you're really writing an API:

1. See [this article](https://blog.codepath.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/) describing your problem.
2. See [the gem](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) that the authors made as a solution.
3. See [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl) on using the gem.

---

**3)** And lastly, the convenient solution. If you have a convenient model relation, this is clean:

Pretending AffiliateLink `belongs_to :user`. And assuming user_token is an accessible attribute of User.

AffiliateLink.rb

```
# have access to user.user_token via relation
def link_with_token
  # some gnarly code that depends on a lot of stuff the model knows
  # that returns a proper link
end

def as_json(options = {})
  super(options.reverse_merge(:methods => :link_with_token, :except => :html_code))
end
```

affiliate_links_controller.rb

```
def index
  @links = Admin::AffiliateLink.all  # TODO, pagination, etc.

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json do
      render json: @links
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @anxiety it might be good to also mention ActiveModel::Serializers , which are a recent addition to Rails - see: https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/active-model-serializers , see also: http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers