# Checking whether current user has voted with thumbs_up gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check if the logged in user has casted a vote for a particular Post. I want to add a property to the Post's JSON attribute to do this. Here is the relevant code for the Post model:

```
  def user_has_voted
    if current_user?
      self.voted_by(current_user)
    end
  end

  def self.public_models(posts)
    posts.to_json({:include => {:user => { :only => [:uid, :email] }, :company => { :only => :name} }, :methods => [:image_url, :total_votes, :user_has_voted]}).html_safe
  end
```

There is a problem with the method user_has_voted because I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Post:0x00000004d8eab0>
```

I think the problem is that the current user is not seen by the scope of the individual Post. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've avoided trying to define to_json or as_json in the models. I think it's better to use something like jbuilder which will allow for use cases as you described. I would highly suggest looking at the railscasts regarding [jbuilder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder).

However, if you want to keep using your current structure, you can follow the example set [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811757/rails-overriding-as-json-for-dynamic-value-is-there-a-smarter-way). In short, you would pass options to an as_json method which would include the current user. They suggest RABL which is an alternative to jbuilder. Best of luck.

Comment: The problem is more that I cannot access current_user from inside of the code. I tried to use jbuilder, and I still cannot access the current_user.

Comment: Did you make current_user a helper method (assuming it's a method in application controller)?